# How to open as popUp instead of New Tab

Tags: javascript, window.open

This question is frequently asking, I am looking for answer too. However I could't find, I have tried lots of example. While trying, I closed pop-up blockers and other restriction.

If new age browsers, automatically block pop-ups, according to me it is unlogical to use 'window.open()'.

However I would like to share with you [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/aswyt2jx/3/) onJsFiddle, maybe one of you lead me to solve.

```
//html
    <button onclick="showAsReservation('http://www.ucaknezaman.com'); return false;">
    Test Link
    </button>
```

//javascript

```
var windowObjectReference = null; // global variable

function showAsReservation(url){    
   if(windowObjectReference == null || windowObjectReference.closed){
        windowObjectReference = window.open(url,
            "_blank","toolbar=no,scrollbars=no, resizable=yes,top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400");
      }
      else
      {
        windowObjectReference.focus();
      };
    windowObjectReference.focus();
}
```

Comment: Works fine in firefox

Comment: It's down to the browser and the end user, and there's no way to force a preferred behaviour.

Comment: it is working fine in firefox  and chrome sir!

Comment: I have tested in Firefox Mac 46.0.1. It did not worked.

Comment: Why not try `alert("hello!");`

Answer (score 1):

Use Below Js to open url in popup

```
<script>
function showAsReservation(url) {
 window.open(url, "", "width=200,height=100");
}
</script>
```